# Android error can't login with email and password

Tags: android

hello I have this app and I have a problem every time I run the app on my phone I get this error:

```
E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 404, errorCode: 803, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: _id}
```

and this error when I try to log in:

```
E/login: http://ciyashop.example.comwp-json/pgs-woo-api/v1/login
E/Exception is: Invalid Api key
```

this is my app structure:

```
/app
  /manifests
    AndroidManifest.xml
  /java
    /com.example.ciyashop
    /com.example.ciyashop (androidTest)
  /java (generated)
    /com.example.ciyashop
    /com.example.ciyashop
  /assets
    /fonts
  /res
    /anim
    /drawable
    /layout
    /mipmap
    /raw
    /values
    /xml
  /res (generated)
    /values
/Gradle Scripts
```

I don't know a thing about android so please tell me what file do you need and in which folder

Comment: @MartinZeitler I tried everything in my mind but didn't get any result

Comment: @MartinZeitler I am really sorry I didn't mean to mean to spam but i really don't know what to do

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have 0 experience with android so it looks like an alien language to me

Comment: The error message is explicit and this would permit searching for the API key, in order to change it - and as you present the question, this is really nothing one could answer, because there is zero code attached, but only irrelevant information.